# hive date format '01-DEC-17' to '2017-12-01'

Tags: hadoop, hive

How to convert *`'13-FEB-18'`* to *`'2018-02-18'`* format

I have tried this

```
select upper(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('13-FEB-18', 'DD-MMM-YY'),'YYYY-MM-dd'));
```

but getting this output.

'2017-12-31'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use lowercase `yy` or `yyyy` and `dd`.

```
select upper(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('13-FEB-18', 'dd-MMM-yy'),'yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

**O/p**

```
2018-02-13
```

*Refer the below link :*

[**Formats**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)